# Magento 2, optional checkout step?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

I'm trying to develop an 'optional' checkout step in the default Magento 2 checkout, required only if a specific shipping method is chosen.

I have my `js/view/custom_step.js` file set up to check the `shippingMethod.method_code` from the `quote` object but it only seems to be set after the `isVisible()` method is called.

Is there a method I can use to remove/add a checkout step on-the-fly during the checkout process?

Comment: Can you add more code lines of your custom module?

Comment: At the moment my extra step is shown permanently - I'm not sure which code is relevant to my question?

Comment: You should add more code lines. It's easier for community.

Comment: did you get some solution